# Unable to use listing with toptesi

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted, fancyvrb, toptesi

Everytime I open a new `listing` the compiler complaints about it.

Try to compile the following example

```
% !TEX options = -shell-escape


\documentclass[%
corpo=12pt,
twoside,
oldstyle,
tipotesi=magistrale,
greek,
evenboxes,
]{toptesi}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
bookmarksopen,
pdfstartview={FitH},
colorlinks,
linkcolor={blue},
citecolor={blue},
urlcolor={blue}
}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{minted}
\setmintedinline{breaklines,breakanywhere}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\begin{listing}

\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

The log file will output these errors

```
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
()
Runaway argument?
d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:45: Paragraph ended before \FVC@VerbatimInput was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.45 
     
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Too many }'s.
\color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup 
                                        
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
You've closed more groups than you opened.
Such booboos are generally harmless, so keep going.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Undefined control sequence.
\endlisting ...floatbox \global \setbox \@currbox 
                                                  \float@makebox \columnwidt...
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vbox 
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ...boxrestore \@fs@pre 
                                                  \@fs@iftopcapt \ifvoid \@f...
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ...@pre \@fs@iftopcapt 
                                                  \ifvoid \@floatcapt \else ...
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ...i \unvbox \@currbox 
                                                  \else \unvbox \@currbox \i...
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Extra \else.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ...box \@currbox \else 
                                                  \unvbox \@currbox \ifvoid ...
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \unvbox 
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ...e \unvbox \@currbox 
                                                  \ifvoid \@floatcapt \else ...
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Extra \fi.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ...\@floatcapt \fi \fi 
                                                  \par \@fs@post \vskip \z@ }
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Undefined control sequence.
\caption@ORI@float@makebox ... \fi \par \@fs@post 
                                                  \vskip \z@ }
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{listing}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

d:/asant/Desktop/master-thesis/mre.tex:46: Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 
                          
l.46 \end{listing}
                  
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.

(mre.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `mre.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `mre.out':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: <no file>
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 33278 strings out of 478927
 666289 string characters out of 2852535
 1096849 words of memory out of 3000000
 50535 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 407491 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 138i,1n,136p,522b,131s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced.

PDF statistics:
 29 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 109 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: the class defines `\listing` as an alias for \VerbatimInput, so it is not an environment, and it expects a file name as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unfortunate that `toptesi.cls` defines its own meaning for `\listing`, actually in `topcoman.sty` which is automatically loaded. On line 83 (current release 2020-09-06 v.6.4.06) we read

```
\let\listing\VerbatimInput
```

Unfortunately, too, `topcoman` is loaded at begin document, so after `minted` that uses `\newfloat` to define a `listing` environment.

I see no reason for `toptesi` to provide `\listing` as an alias to `\VerbatimInput`, but it's there.

Besides making your own copy of `topcoman.sty` that removes the offending line, I can offer a workaround.

```
\documentclass[%
  corpo=12pt,
  twoside,
  oldstyle,
  tipotesi=magistrale,
  greek,
  evenboxes,
]{toptesi}

%%% Packages and libraries
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{svg} % No inkscape on my machine
\usepackage{minted}

%%% workaround for listing
% save the current meaning of \listing
\let\savedlisting\listing
% at the right spot, restore the meaning
\AtBeginDocument{\let\listing\savedlisting}
%%% end of workaround

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz-uml} % no tikz-uml on my machine
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% hyperref should be last
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
  bookmarksopen,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={blue},
  citecolor={blue},
  urlcolor={blue},
}

%%% Settings

\setmintedinline{breaklines,breakanywhere}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\begin{listing}

\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

(I commented out `inputenc` because it's no longer needed, if `utf8` is assumed; also `svg` because on this machine I don't have `inkscape` and `tikz-uml` because I'd have to download it; uncomment them.)

Of course, it would be *much* better if `topcoman` had

```
\@ifundefined{listing}{\let\listing\VerbatimInput}{}
```